# Construir Excel con función

Tags: vba, ms-access, vb6

Estoy intentando construir un documento en Excel desde Visual Basic 6 de MS-Access con el siguiente código, el cual llama la función **TraeDatosCorteAnterior**, que realiza una consulta a la Base de Datos, genera abre la aplicación Excel y agrega una Hoja de Trabajo, sin embargo al continuar generando el documento desde la función **ConstruyeTablayCampo**, la aplicación de arroja un error 424 con el mensaje siguiente **"Se requiere un objeto"**:

**Declaración del objeto excel**

```
Option Compare Database
Dim ba As Excel.Application
```

**Función Inicial**

```
  Public Sub TraeDatosCorteAnterior()

    RstName = "SELECT conc.CP, conc.etapa, conc.total FROM t_conclusion as conc;"
    Dim dbs As Database
    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    Dim iRec As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim RstOrig As Recordset
    Dim nTotalReg As Integer
    Dim nCP As Integer
    Dim nEtapa As Integer 
    Dim nTotal As Integer

    Set RstOrig = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(RstName, dbOpenDynaset)
    RstOrig.Sort = fldName
    Dim RstSorted As Recordset
    Set RstSorted = RstOrig.OpenRecordset()
    RstOrig.Sort = fldName
    Dim RstSorted As Recordset
    Set RstSorted = RstOrig.OpenRecordset()
    RstSorted.MoveLast
    RstSorted.MoveFirst

    nTotalReg = RstSorted.RecordCount

    nCP = RstSorted("CP")

    nEtapa = IIf(IsNull(RstSorted("etapa")) = True, 0, RstSorted("etapa"))
    nTotal = IIf(IsNull(RstSorted("Total")) = True, 0, RstSorted("Total"))

    RstSorted.MoveNext


    Set ba = New Excel.Application
    Set xlwbook = ba.Workbooks.Add
    ba.Visible = True

    ConstruyeTablayCampo "Cuadro I", "Cuenta Pública", "A", "A", ba, False, 1

  End Sub
```

**Función que construye el documento**, desde la primera línea marca el error.

```
 Sub ConstruyeTablayCampo(ByRef sHoja As String, ByRef sTexto As String, ByRef col1 As String, ByRef col2 As String, ByRef ba As Excel.Application, Optional bCreaHoja As Boolean, Optional nHoja As Integer)

        Set xlsheet = xlwbook.Sheets.Item(nHoja)
        xlwbook.Sheets.Item(nHoja).Name = sHoja

        xlsheet.Cells.Range("A11:A11") = sTexto
        Worksheets("Cuadro I").Range("B:B,D:D,H:H,J:J,N:N,Q:Q").ColumnWidth = 1

        With xlsheet.Cells.Range(col1 & "11:" & col2 & "12")
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                .WrapText = True
                .Select
                .Font.Bold = True
                .MergeCells = True
                .Interior.Color = RGB(244, 244, 244)
        End With

End Sub
```

Gracias por adelantado, espero puedan ayudarme!

Comment: Un par de cosas, si declaras `ba` de manera pública, justo debajo del `Option Compare`, no necesitas luego pasarla como parámetro en la función. No se pierde su valor al cambiar de función, declara `ba` dentro de `TraeDatosCorteAnterior()`. Por otro lado, no veo en ninguna parte dónde has declarado `xlwbook`ni `xlsheet`, tampoco dónde le has dado valor a `xlwbook`. Para evitar estos errores te recomiendo utilizar `Option Explicit`debajo o encima de tu `Option compare`. Por último, `Worksheets("Cuadro I")` = `xlsheet` así que utiliza `xlsheet`porque ya la tienes referenciada, cuando lo arregles

Comment: ¿Cómo tienes definido `xlwbook`? Suponiendo que sea pública, prueba con `Set xlsheet = xlwbook.WorkSheets(nHoja)`. Y otra cosa, ¿Por qué estás pasando todos los argumentos como `ByRef` si en realidad estás pasando valores?